# Apple Pay stays in a processing state with stripe

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, applepay

Why when paying through Apple Pay, my payment makes the payment, but the modal window always remains in a processing state. This is on the web on React app. I make it by this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMCsJfJyQKA&t=1304s. How can I close this window after successful payment?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Please update your question with more details.  Is this on the web or Apple Pay in a native app?  What method are you using to provide Apple Pay as a payment option?  Which Stripe product/library/SDK are you using?  Are you getting any error messages in your console/debugger/etc. when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

In order to dismiss the Apple Pay sheet you need to implement a `paymentRequest.on` listener which calls `.complete()` on the event provided to the handler with a single argument that's either `'success'` or `'fail'`.

Stripe has [a guide and sample code](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?html-or-react=react#react-complete-payment) for this which explains things in detail.